# IWordBreaker Implementation in C# causes MemoryAccessViolation

Tags: c#, windows, indexing, service

I have inherited some code that makes use of the Windows IWordBreaker and IWordSink interfaces. There is an issue when multiple threads execute and use this code (to break multiple documents concurrently) - The IWordBreaker.BreakText() method throws a MemoryAccessViolation error.

Does anyone know how to use this type of Exception to get to the root cause of the error?

Also - Documentation on these interfaces and how to use them within C# appears to be rare. Does anyone know of any good sites, books, or other material that would help me understand these interfaces better?

Many Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Why isn't this thread closed yet?  Do you need something else?

Comment: im having a similar problem...except mine occurs only in release mode !

Comment: @Mulki, have you implemented your own WordBreaker in C# or you just access an existing WordBreaker through C#? I am desperately looking for some code samples on this topic...

Comment: Oleg : this was in my older project...the issue was not resolved last i checked...will have to dig up and check for code samples...what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: @Mulki, I want to implement my own WordBreaker in C#, to use it with SQL Full Text Search